# How to select specific columns from tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am training my Tensorflow model on data from a CSV file preprocessed by tf.data.Dataset. However, I want the model to fork into three branches corresponding to a different set of csv columns, and model.fit requires a separate dataset for each output. All columns of the CSV file need to undergo the same preprocessing, so the most efficient way of preparing it would be to load the whole file, process it, and then split the dataset into three parts. However, I am struggling to find a way of doing so.

I hoped that dataset.map would allow me to select some columns using the following operation:

```
dset = dset.map(lambda x: x[[1, 2, 3, 7]])
```

but it seems that tensorflow interprets it as `x[1][2][3][7]` instead.

The only working way of creating separate datasets that I've found was to do it from the beginning:

```
y = []
for cls, keys in output_classes.items():
    tmp = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(data_path, [tf.int32 for i in keys], select_cols=keys)
    [...]
    y.append(tmp)
y = tf.data.Dataset.zip(tuple(y))
```

Unfortunately, it producess a lot of unnecessary overhead and immensely slows down the training.

Is there a way of splitting tf.data.Dataset object by a subset of features?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather):

```
tf.gather(tf.constant([1,2,3,4]), [1,2,3])
# ouputs : array([2, 3, 4])
```

If you have high dimensional data, use [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd).

Answer (score 1):

This solution has worked for me by modifying tornikeo's answer with a .map().

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[1,2,3,4], 
                                              [5,6,7,8]])
dataset_filter = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.gather(x, [0, 2], axis=0))
result = list(dataset_filter.as_numpy_iterator())
print(result)

# Outputs array([1, 3], dtype=int32), array([5, 7])
```